# Insight.Database.Schema SchemaGroup purpose

Tags: orm

What is the practical aspect of `Insight.Database.Schema`'s `SchemaGroup`? Why and how should i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some more information on the wiki:

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database.Schema/wiki/Schema-Groups

A summary:

You can use Schema Groups to install multiple schemas into the same database.

Sometimes you have more than one program or component that needs to install SQL into a database. You may also want to manage their schemas separately (perhaps on a separate release cycle).

For example, you have two components in your application. A user membership library and your application code. They both have their own SQL schema.